# How to ensure that T['someDynamicField'] is of type K

Tags: typescript

```
  interface Props<KeyType, T>  {
    keyField : keyof T; //what field to use as key. Key of type KeyType
    data: T[]; //Data provided to table
  }
```

How can I ensure that `T[keyField]` is of type KeyType?

What I want to achieve:

```js
//selection is of type KeyType[]
//props implements interface Props

selection.filter(key => !props.data.filter(item => key === item[props.keyField]).length).forEach(
  key => { /*...*/})
```

to be valid. Right now if I implement Props with KeyType == string, it gives me an error:

```
TS2367: This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and 'T[keyof T]' have no overlap.
```

Comment: from your description is not understable what you want to do.

Comment: the question is not understandable

Comment: question is edited to provide more clarity

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this perhaps?

```
interface Props<T, K extends keyof T> {
  keyField: K
  data: T[K]
}
```

Its called a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html). If that's **not** what you're looking for then please expand your question a bit, so that it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some utility types I use to accomplish this:

```
//gets the set of keys on Obj which are assignable to Type
export type FilteredProperties<Obj, Type> = { [key in keyof Obj]: Obj[key] extends Type ? key : never }[keyof Obj];

//gets the set of keys on Obj which can be assigned from Type
export type FilteredPropertiesAssign<Obj, Type> = { [key in keyof Obj]: Type extends Obj[key] ? key : never }[keyof Obj];
```

To use:

```
interface example {
    field1: string;
    field2: number;
}


interface Props<T, TargetType, KeyType extends FilteredProperties<T, TargetType>> {
    keyField: KeyType;
    data: T[];
}

type test1 = Props<example, string, "field1">; //ok

type test2 = Props<example, number, "field2">; //ok

type test3 = Props<example, string, "field2">; //error
```